# How to show only clicking legend data in c3js chart?

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I have a line chart with multiple data. Here is the sample of my chart.

[image: legend]

Normally legend data are automatically show/hide if I click that legend on chart.

But after I adding a function in legend like this,

```
legend: {
        position: 'right',
        item: {
                onclick: function (d) { 
                            console.log("onclick", d); 
                            show(d); //when I click legend show some data
                }
            }
},
```

I don't get automatically show/hide if I click that legend on chart. But its not important for me.

Instead of this, I want to show only clicking legend data in chart. if I click `data1` legend, I want to show only `data1` line in chart and hide another `data2`,`data3` and `data4` line in chart.

But, I don't have any idea how to do this. I'm very appreciate for any suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now, I can solve my problem. Here is the code.

```
legend: {
        position: 'right',
        item: {
                onclick: function (d) { 
                        console.log("onclick", d); //data1
                        show(d); //when I click legend show some data
                        chart.hide();
                        chart.show(d);
                }
            }
},
```

First, I use `chart.hide()`. This function will hide all data on chart.

After that, I use `chart.show(d)` and it can show only data of user click because I add user clicking legend as an argument.

> Note: `show(d)` is not related with `chart.show(d)`. Just a function
>   that I create for my need.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you stumbling across this like I did while looking for a way to focus on a single series from a legend click (I'm used to a double-click doing this), it seems `c3` added the ability to use `alt-click` to focus on a single legend item. See the commit [here](https://gitlab.eterfund.ru/charts/c3-closed/commit/6a4d0179d143c7a9e8ace6c3ba7365c7952ddaf6). It turns out this works in `billboard.js` as well, which is a fork of `c3`.